# installations of pg_ivm in windows machine

Tags: database, postgresql

For creating incremental materialized view in postgesql, pg_ivm module is developed by a team on github. link: github.com/sraoss/pg_ivm

I face some problem while installing pg_ivm module in postgres on my windows machine. Can you please kindly help me?

How do I install pg_ivm in postgres on my windows machine?

I use postgresql 14 version. Is pg_ivm module included as built-in feature in any postgresql version?